# Laravel migration error, pluck() undefined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, migration, laravel-5.1

I have a fairly simple migration that produces the following error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]          
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Collection::pluck()
```

I can rollback but I cannot migrate up. I'm using `"laravel/framework": "5.1.*@dev",` and this is the migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('tutorials', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('url');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->string('image');
    });
}
```

The `pluck` method is defined in `Illuminate\Support\Collection` so I'm sort of at a loss. I've run `composer dump`, as well. Any ideas?

Comment: you are using the `@dev` branch so probably there are some things they need to fix ... why don't you try the stable version `v5.1.4`?

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/upgrade#upgrade-5.1.0 quote: The following Laravel features have been deprecated and will be removed entirely with the release of Laravel 5.2 in December 2015: (...) The Eloquent and query builder `pluck` method has been deprecated and renamed to `value`. (...) The collection `fetch` method has been deprecated in favor of the `pluck` method. (...) Maybe you are seeing the implementations of this?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using laravel version `"5.1.*"` which will evaluate to 5.1.4 
This is because @dev is constantly under development and not all of its functional may be in place. Today one thing will work while the next day another fails. Recommendation is to use a stable version then run the migrations to see if they work.